# JMS, ActiveMQ - weird string prepended to my text message body

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, quarkus

I'm developing a producer-consumer application. The two are connected through an ActiveMQ queue.
When I try to send a message, the following string is prepended before the content:

```
Sr�)�x-opt-jms-destQ�x-opt-jms-msg-typeQSs�d
�/ID:72a1faef-ff5a-40dd-aecc-61e94c0a432a:1:1:1-1@�queue://name_of_my_queue@@@@@@�~
�Sw�
actual message
```

The message is detected by the consumer as an ActiveMQBytesMessage and there's no way for it to get its content correctly.
Here are the code snippets for the producer and consumer:

**Consumer**

```
 String receiveMessage() {
  MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(session.createQueue(receiverQueue));
  String content = "";


  try {
    Message message = consumer.receive();
    if(message instanceof TextMessage) {
      content = ((TextMessage) message).getText(); 
    }
    else {
      BytesMessage byteMessage = (BytesMessage) message;
      byte[] byteData = null;
      byteData = new byte[(int) byteMessage.getBodyLength()];
      byteMessage.readBytes(byteData);
      byteMessage.reset();
      content =  new String(byteData);
    }
  }
  catch (JMSException | JsonProcessingException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
  }
  return content;
}
```

**Producer**

```
void sendMessage() {
   JMSContext context;

    try {
       context = connectionFactory.createContext(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
        TextMessage tm = context.createTextMessage("TestMessage");
        producer.send(context.createQueue(myQueue), tm);
      }
    }
    catch (JMSException | JsonProcessingException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The producer is in a quarkus application.
How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you are not using the proper encoding?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: I figured out the problem was related to the broker: I was using rmohr/activemq, switching to artemis-activemq solved the issue

Comment: Please put your solution into an actual answer and mark it as correct to help others who run into this problem in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who might run into the same issue: I figured out the problem was the broker. I was using a `rmohr/activemq` container and I solved it by switching to `vromero/activemq-artemis`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).